# C# model validation shows valid Date range as invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

My model has a date field like this:

```
[Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "This field is required.")]
[Range(typeof(DateTime), "1/1/2000", "1/1/2010", ErrorMessage = "Date is out of Range")]
public string DOB { get; set; }
```

In my view I have this field:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DOB, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "dob", type = "Date" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.DOB)
```

---

The date is always invalid, even if the date is within range.

[image]

---

Comment: try specify format DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:mm-dd-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]

Comment: @Nonik Thanks for the reply.  I'm getting the same result when using DisplayFormat

Comment: You DOB is a string type, but you trying to validate DateTime type. You can make a custom validator or convert  string to DateTime and back.

Answer (score 1):

You DOB is a string type, but you trying to validate DateTime type. You can make a custom validator or you can try to make working something like this

```
public string DOB 
{
get {  return DOBDateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"); }
set  { DobDateTime= DateTime.Parse(value);  }
}


[NotMapped]

[Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required.")]
[Range(typeof(DateTime), "1/1/2000", "1/1/2010", ErrorMessage = "Date is out of Range")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime DOBDateTime { get; set; }
```

in this case you will  have to use DOBDateTime for the user interface only

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the validation with a Datetime prop?
Something like it:

```
[Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required.")]
[Range(typeof(DateTime), "1/1/2000", "1/1/2010", ErrorMessage = "Date is out of Range")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
```

Comment: Tried this and got the same result

Comment: You can try a custom ValidationAttribute. You can find a tutorial here https://newbedev.com/is-there-a-rangeattribute-for-datetime